# How can I roughly estimate the load in this case?

Tags: batteries, load

A DC device operates with three industrial AA batteries meaning 1.5V times three = 4.5V. Besides that I only know that the approximate operating time is is 4 hours.

Is that possible to estimate the load in terms of resistance roughly?

Battery info: Three AA Type 1.5V 1500 mAH in series making 4.5V in total.

Comment: How do you know the batteries are in series and not parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 × 1.5 V, 900 mAh gives 4.5 V, 900 mAh.

Run time = 4 hours so \$ I = \frac {900\ \text {mAh}}{4 \ \text h} = 225 \ \text {mA} \$.

The effective load resistance is given by \$ R = \frac {V}{I}  = \frac {4.5}{225} \$ which will be left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I found more info on batteries : AA Type 1.5V 1500mAH times 3  = 4.5V in total

Comment: Can you work it out yourself now?

Comment: Yes I can thanks!